# For what values of real parameter $a$ the equation has exactly one solution in $[0,\pi)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> For what values of real parameter $a$ the equation has exactly one solution in $[0,\pi)$: $$\sin (2x)\sin(4x)-\sin x\sin(3x)=a$$

I've managed to prove transform it in to:

$$ \cos (4x)-\cos (6x) = 2a$$ and then $$\sin (5x)\sin x =a$$ So clearly $a\notin \mathbb{R}\setminus (-1,1)$ but could not managed to do more. Any hint appart to calculate the derivative which lead me no where.

The graph of $\color{green}{x\mapsto \sin (5x)\sin x}$ and the graph of $\color{blue}{s\mapsto 16s^3-20s^2+5s}$ where $s= \sin^2x$, so the later is defined on $[0,1)$.

[image]

Comment: Judging from the picture it should just be $a=1$

Comment: Judging from the graph any horizontal line of the equation $x=a$ crosses the graph twice UNLESS $ x=1$ in that case $x=\pi$ is the only solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can note that if $x\in(0,\pi)$ is a solution to $\sin(5x)\sin(x)=a$, then also $\pi-x$ is a solution, because
$$
\sin(5(\pi-x))=\sin(5\pi-5x)=\sin(\pi-5x)=\sin(5x)
$$
and similarly for $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$.

Thus the unique solution must be for $x=0$ or $x=\pi-x$, that is, $x=\pi/2$; however, the expression also vanishes for $x=\pi/5$. So the only value can be $a=1$.

Indeed, if $\sin(5x)\sin(x)=1$, then both factors have to be $1$, so the only solution is indeed $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: This trick shows that i would not need to transform the expression at all.

Comment: @Aqua Yes, in the original equation, the first two terms change sign with $x\to\pi-x$ and the other two don't. So it's invariant under the substitution. The problem would be more interesting with $[0,\pi/2]$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the identities $\cos2t = 2\cos^2 t -1$ and $\cos3t = 4\cos^3 t -3\cos t$ to express $$ \cos 4x-\cos 6x = 2a$$

as

$$4y^3-2y^2-3y+2a+1=0$$

where $y = \cos 2x$. Then, set the discriminate of the cubic equation so that it has single root. For the given equation to have only one root in $[0,\pi)$, the value of $a$ satisfies,

$$\frac{20\sqrt{10}-25}{108} \le a<1$$